# How could I use asarmor in electron-forge?

Tags: electron-forge, asar

How could I use asarmor in electron-forge?

I want to use asarmor to make my electron app more stronger,How could I do with the electron-forge?

Comment: Have you seen the [hooks documention](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration#hooks) of electron-forge ? I wonder if you can't use asarmor in [postPackage](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration#postpackage) ?

Comment: Did you already fix this issue? I have the same question